# How to remove one item from a vector of objects in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have the following C++ class,

```
class rec
{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

And in my main function I have a vector with `rec` objects,

```
rec r1,r2,r3;
r1.height = r1.width = 1;
r2.height = r2.width = 2;
r3.height = r3.width = 3;

vector<rec> rvec = { r1,r2,r3 };
```

Now I want to erase one item from `rvec` with the following method call,

```
rvec.erase(remove(rvec.begin(), rvec.end(), r_remove), rvec.end());
```

But I got this error:

> C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand
>   of type 'rec' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: You need to implement operator==() for the rec class to allow comparison between rec objects. This is what remove uses to find the entry that matches r_remove.

Comment: You can also try [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) in the case you can't implement `operator==` for your class

Comment: For future reference you should note that every algorithm as a set of requirements for the types it accepts. Read the documentation and learn what those requirement are. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is a good place to bookmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to overload operator== for your custom data structure `rec`

```
class rec
{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    bool operator==(const rec&  rhs) {
        return (width == rhs.width) && (height == rhs.height);
    }
};
```

since `remove` compares values via operator==

Comment: Thanks @Starl1ght, It worked perfectly. I only had to add the class name "rec" to the operator definition: bool operator==(const rec& rhs)

Comment: @MHS2015 yep, a little mistypo, sorry :)